# redirect to another page

Tags: php, javascript

< type="button" value="PRINT" onClick="window.open('print.php?id=&sec=&subj=&type=viewrec2&Year=&faci= ','mywindow','width=800,height=800,left=0,top=100,screenX=0,screenY=100')">

when i click this button im being redirected into a new window. the problem is that on the main page where this button is located i want it also to redirect it to the previous page on that the same window how can i do that im using php and javascript?

Comment: +1 - Interesting question, not sure why it was voted down...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<input type="button" value="PRINT" onClick="window.open('print.php?id=&sec=&subj=&type=viewrec2&Year=&faci= ','mywindow','width=800,height=800,left=0,top=100,screenX=0,screenY=100');history.back()">
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
history.go(-1);
```

changing the code to:

```
<input type="button" value="PRINT" onClick="window.open('print.php?id=&sec=&subj=&type=viewrec2&Year=&faci= ','mywindow','width=800,height=800,left=0,top=100,screenX=0,screenY=100');history.go(-1)">
```